# Flutter: VerticalDivider is not shown

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this widget tree:

```
Scaffold
  AppBar
  Column
    Center
    SingleChildScrollView
    FutureBuilder
       Container
       Flex
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              onPressed: () => {},
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.star,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "4.5",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            VerticalDivider(
                              width: 1,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              thickness: 1,
                              indent: 2,
                              endIndent: 2,
                            ),
                            FlatButton() //like above
                            VerticalDivider()//like above
                            FlatButton()//like above
```

The codes make this image:
[image]

I wondered why **VerticalDivider** is not shown ?

> I am using `flutter_linux_1.17.0-stable` flutter sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this happen, when you parent widget does't have specific height.

Moreover, if you look implementation of VerticalDivider they didn't specify size of sizedbox or container that's why it doesn’t have any height, any by IntrinsicHeight widget, we can specify child widget should be hight of parent.

Wrap your row widget with **[IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html)**.

```
Flex
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
        IntrinsicHeight( // added widget
              Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[
```